# WP Meta Information Not Showing on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata, meta-tags

I am trying to add some meta data on my custom theme.

so far I have add on all pages:

```
<head>
        <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no' />
        <meta name="description" content="<?php bloginfo('description'); ?>">
```

The code works good on all the page except on the front page.. when i try to post it on Facebook it shows

http://myblog.com (title)
Just another WordPress site (blog Description)

I have changed the description, empty the browser cache but I don't know why is it still showing that description.

My front page is a static page with castom php.

Any Idea why this is happening?

I have also downloaded a meta data plugin but seems not to work